# android spinner broken in SDK 11

Tags: android, sdk, spinner

I found this trying to get a simple spinner example to work.  It worked with minSdkVersion="8" but I can't get the with the current versions to work.
In the code below I get radio buttons in the pull-down with the minSdkVersion="10" but lose them with the minSdkVersion="11".
Other than the change missing RadioButton, everything works.  I can't find any mention of a change in the docs or questions about problems with the Spinner, but am probably looking in the wrong places and don't really know where to look.
Any help appreciated.
Sorry for such a long post...

My MainActivity looks like:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
    private Spinner createSpinner(int id, String fmtString) {
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(id);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
            categories.add(String.format(fmtString, i));
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter
            = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this
                , android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
                , categories);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        return spinner;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Spinner s = createSpinner(R.id.layout_spinner, "activity spinner %02d");
        // set initial selection to the fifth element (= 06)
        s.setSelection(5);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int itemIndex,
            long itemId) {

        String selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(itemIndex).toString();
        Toast.makeText(
            parent.getContext()
            , "Selected item: \"" + selectedItem + "\""
            , Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

The Android Manifest looks like:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.spinnerdemo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

And the layout looks like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/layout_spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try to set this way : dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);

Comment: i have post my ans can you please approve and upvote if is useful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice)‌​;
```